# Remove everything after a specific number of digits

Tags: javascript

I have like this html code that displays a numbers :

```
<span class="code">12345678-001</span>
```

There is a solution with Javascript that allows to remove evreything after 8 digits and after the " - " ?

```
<span class="code">12345678</span>
```

Comment: Yes, there is a solution! But, you should try something yourself first, as this is not a free coding service. ;-)

Comment: `"12345678-001".match(/^\d{8}/)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own (for example google) and tell what you've tried to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of the fields you want to change have the `code` CSS class, you could do like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.code').forEach(num => num.innerHTML = /^\d{8}/.exec(num.innerHTML)[0]);
```

```html
<span class="code">12345678-001</span>

<span class="code">12345678</span>
```

Comment: You need to use `{8}` instead of `+`, because the latter also matches "123456789-001".

Comment: Not sure what OP wants but yeah you might be right